# jQuery Form posting the last post value

Tags: jquery

My problem is : when I hit enter the lastly posted value prepend to the current post value every time.

- first occurence: 'abc' hit enter -> console: abc
- second occurence: 'def' hit enter -> console: abc def
- third occurence  : 'ghi' hit enter -> console: abc def ghi
  ...
- and so on

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {

  $('body').on('keydown', '.form-post-comment', function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13 && $(this).val() != '' && !event.shiftKey) {
         $(this).parent('form').submit();
         console.log($(this).val());
      }

    });
  });
  ```

Comment: a) use `event.which` instead of `event.keyCode`, b) use `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()`, c) u really need to delegate from the body? there isn't a more localized container u can delegate from?, and d) clear your value after each submission, i.e. `this.value = '';`

Answer (score 1):

The clearing of the values are the important piece, but figured I would provide a more optimized way to do this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.form-post-container').on('keyup','.form-post-comment',function(e){
        if((e.which === 13) && this.value && !e.shiftKey){
            var self = this;

            $(self).parents('form').submit();
            console.log(self.value);
            self.value = '';
        }
    });
});
```

Notice the more localized container usage than `body`, the use of `e.which` (specifically created for cross-browser quirks), the use of `&& this.value` instead of `&& this.value !== ''` (as just doing `&& this.value` verifies that it indeed has a value), and the caching of `this`. I also modified the use of `parent` to `parents` to account for any nested inputs, but if you know for a fact it will always be 1 step up the DOM tree just use `parent()`, as providing the tag name in there provides unnecessary validation that it is indeed a form.